# XSLT1.0 find and relace

Tags: xslt-1.0

I'm having some problems replacing a string within a string using XSL 1.0. I've read various threads on this site and others but just can't put my finger on why my method will not work. For the purposes of this question I've dumbed down the data a little but you'll get the list, hopefully.

Here is my XML file

```
<StatementReportOnlActivityByGame>
    <GameName>TESTMATCH5</GameName>
    <StatementReportOnlActivityByGameDetail>
        <DetailDesc>1ASALES TESTMATCH5</DetailDesc>
        <GrossAmount>18.000</GrossAmount>
    </StatementReportOnlActivityByGameDetail>
    <StatementReportOnlActivityByGameDetail>
        <DetailDesc>3AVALIDS TESTMATCH5</DetailDesc>
        <GrossAmount>10.000</GrossAmount>
    </StatementReportOnlActivityByGameDetail>
    <StatementReportOnlActivityByGameDetail>
        <DetailDesc>4ACOMMISSIONS TESTMATCH5</DetailDesc>
        <GrossAmount>0.000</GrossAmount>
    </StatementReportOnlActivityByGameDetail>
</StatementReportOnlActivityByGame>
```

Requirement : In the output i need to replace the `TESTMATCH5` with `TESTMATCH F5`

XSL file is

```
<xsl:template name="string-replace-all">
    <xsl:param name="text" />
    <xsl:param name="replace" />
    <xsl:param name="by" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($text, $replace)">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$replace)" />
            <xsl:value-of select="$by" />
            <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,$replace)" />
                <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace" />
                <xsl:with-param name="by" select="$by" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$text" />
        </xsl:otherwise> 
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Calling Template

```
<xsl:cal-template name="string-replace-all">
    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="lsp:DetailDesc" />
    <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="TESTMATCH5" />
    <xsl:with-param name="by" select="'TESTMATCH F5'" />
</xsl:cal-template>
```

Comment: Please correct the formatting of the sample and post content.

Comment: Please post a **complete** stylesheet: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve